# Google app script time trigger error

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function try_A(){
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1");
   var url = range.getValue();
   var url_array = url.split('=');
   var id = url_array[1];
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); 
}
```

So the function try_A reads the url that links to the google drive folder, and parse it to get the folder id. However, if i set a time trigger to call it for example every 1 min, then it keeps notifying me an error like couldn't find info for the corresponding id, or i don't have permission.The error corresponds to this line: "var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);". But if i run this function manually, there is no problem. Why is that? Thx in advance.

Comment: I'd try to log the value of id to see what's up with it. One possible issue is your use of `getActiveSheet`; this method is convenient when a script is used interactively, but not really appropriate for a timed trigger. Use `getSheetByName(name)` instead.

Comment: There is no active sheet when the ***time*** trigger runs the script.  The only time a script can detect an active sheet, or range is with something like an On Edit or On Change trigger that runs from an user editing the open spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are always getting the cell "B1", so you can use:

```
function try_A() {
  var ss,sh,range,url;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('name here');
  range = sh.getRange("B1");

  Logger.log('ss: ' + ss)//View the Logs to see what is printed
  Logger.log('sh: ' + sh)
  Logger.log('range: ' + range)

  url = range.getValue();
  Logger.log('url: ' + url)

  var url_array = url.split('=');
  var id = url_array[1];
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); 
}
```